# How to use Multithreading to crawl webpages in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

How do I use multithreading to repeat the same method to read webpages.

I have a list of urls that I send to my method that reads a webpage. I want to use multithreading to have the program read 5 webpages at the same time to speed it up.

Comment: How is multi-threading going to speed up reading web pages? Is the bottleneck at the processor cores or at the reading in of the data?

Comment: Of course multithreading is speeding it up, as the bottleneck for moderately sized web pages is usually the establishment of the connection and server dependent speed limits.

Comment: Well, if the method uses Non-blocking I/O, then multi-threading won't speed it much up.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) . If you set the pool size to 5 and create a subclass of Runnable, that executes your method, you have everything you need.